# Webtoon about a female lead who keeps reincarnating after being killed by male lead

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation, webcomics

I don't remember much; unfortunately is has been very long since I read it.

She keeps dying by the hands of the male lead. He is a tyrant and she knows she somehow has to say something interesting so that he doesn't kill her. Every time, she gets reincarnated and ends up at the same point. I think at the end of the chapter, she manages to pique his interest and so avoids death.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this? Was it in full colour or mostly black & white? What sort of world/time period was the story set in? And do you recall the hair colour/s of the female and male leads?